# how to insert primary key table value into foreign key table using dropdownlist select item usin sql server and c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have three table:

1. Categorycrt
2. Itemcrt
3. Pricefix

Categorycrt table has a primary key ProductId Itemcrt table has a primary key ItemId Pricefix table has a primary key PriceId and two foreign keys ProductId from categorycrt table and ItemId from Itemcrt table

And on the design page for pricefix I have dropdownlist for Item and another dropdownlist for Product. on selecting the category and item from the dropdownlist I wanted to enter the corresponding itemId and ProductId to the price fix table

What I want is by selecting the item dropdown list the corresponding ItemId(primary key) of the Itemcrt Table should be inserted in the ItemId(foreign key) of the Pricefix table...

Kindly Help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to get ProductId and ItemId and you can get this value from dropdown selected value. Once user selection final then on click update/ok button you can insert data/record in you "Pricefix" table.

Comment: int intProductId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlProduct.SelectedValue);
int intItemd = Convert.ToInt32(ddlItem.SelectedValue); this way you can get ProductId and ItemId. After that you just have to pass this id in your stored procedure which is insert data in "Pricefix" table.